# System.MissingMethodException Method Not Found Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm running into the following exception on my client workstation when trying to update the application:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 
Method not found: 'Void CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.set_CachedPageNumberPerDoc(Int32)'.
at OpusRw.CrystalReports.CryRepView.InitializeComponent()
at OpusRw.CrystalReports.CryRepView..ctor() in   
   c:\cli_code\OPUSfin\OPUSfin\CrystalReports\CryRepView.cs:line 21
   at OPUSfin.SubForms.PrintScreen.btInsertion_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  
   c:\cli_code\OPUSfin\OPUSfin\SubForms\PrintScreen.cs:line 55
```

However when I debug the code locally I have no problem.  (The updates did not even alter the code in question).

I initially assumed this was a .dll error and Have tried cleaning the solution, removing and re-adding the .dll's to no avail.

What other things can I try to resolve the issue ?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions on your machine? I have hit this before when .NET was finding an assembly in the cache(incorrect version) instead of the build directory(correct version). Might not help but certainly has the smell of that kind of situation.

Comment: No go I've tried it on several machines and restarted or flushed out the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I program in vb and had a similar issue.
Have a vb.net app with many screens/forms each with a CrystalReportViewr (crv).
Screens developed prior to 7/2014 work fine. Those developed after wouldn't load and got the error:
'Void CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.set_CachedPageNumberPerDoc(Int32)'.
Solution:
Open 'SolutionExplorer'.
Go to form in question and expand the '+' sign.
Right click on YourFormName.Designer.vb and choose 'View Code'.
In resultant code window scroll to find the name of the CrystalReportViewer.
Comment out line: "Me.crv1.CachedPageNumberPerDoc = 10".

I recompiled and updated the app on user's machines and it worked.

Comment: I am a c# developer. I got the same issue. This worked for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: This happened to me as well.  C# / VS2013.  Nearly drove me nuts until I found this.  May http://stackoverflow.com/users/3557673/oldprogrammer be forever praised.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3561339).  I don't know how or why this happened but the Crystal Reports Runtime Engine Must be updated to the newest version (Even though i didn't update it on the developement box).  Hope that helps someone with the same issue.