# Crystal Reports 13 unhandled exception

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I am working on a project, when I deployed my project to a windows 7 workstation I am prompted with this error message. Any help is very well appreciated.. Thank you

```
Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will      ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click QUIT, the application will close prematurely.

An error occured creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. The error is: Method not found: 'Void CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.set_SHowCopyButton(Boolean)'.
```

Comment: Does this solution help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963275/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found-crystal-reports

Comment: I uninstalled and installed the latest version but still the same problem occurred.

Comment: Can you give more details about what version of CR you have installed like 64 bit or 32 bit.

Comment: I am developing on a 64bit platform and deploy my project on a 32bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a report for a 32-bit machine, you should try using the 32-bit version of the software. There could be some incompatibilities between the two which is a frequent issue when sharing files between 32-bit and 64-bit applications. This isn't to say it's the only possible issue, but it's a decent guess anyway.

You could also make sure that you have all dependencies for CR installed. Things like Visual studios redistributables and VB\C++ redistributables. Also, make sure that all of the dependencies are 32-bit, although my understanding is this occurring on the 32-bit machine anyway.